# tensorflow - reason there is no numpy out equivalent parameter

Tags: tensorflow

## Backgrund

In Tensorflow, even when using mutable variables, it looks there is no `out` option as in numpy to specify the location to store the calculation result. One of the reason why the calculation gets slower is the temporary copy as explained [From Python to Numpy](https://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/from-python-to-numpy/#temporary-copy) and in my understanding re-using the existing buffer would avoid such copies.

## Question

Would like to understand why there is no `out` option equivalent in Tensorflow. For instance [matmul](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/matmul) appear to have no such option to specify the location.Is it because by design Tensorflow will avoid making temporary copies or does it always create temporary copies.

It appears there is no `copy` indexing or `view` indexing concepts that numpy has. When an array is extracted from an existing array, is it a shallow copy (view) or a deep copy or it depends?

Please advise where to look at to understand the internal behavior overview similar to [From Python to Numpy](https://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/from-python-to-numpy/#memory-layout) that gives good insights into its internal architecture and performance considerations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensorflow produces computations graphs, which are highly optimized in terms of the data flow. For example, if some of the stated computations are not needed to produce the final result, TF would not evaluate them. Moreover, TF compiles procedures to its own low-level operations. Hence `out` parameter of `numpy` does not make sense in this context.

Thus, TF internally optimizes all steps of the dataflow, and you do not need to provide any instructions. You can optimize the procedure of getting the result as an algorithm, but not how the algorithmworks internally.

To get familiar with the idea what a computational graph is, consider reading [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_graphs#what_are_graphs)